# String functions in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Here is a sample of python function that I use. Is it possible / practical to use a similar function written in mysql stored procedure?

```
import itertools
import jellyfish
def dropdup(mystr):
    mytuple=tuple(set(mystr.lower().split()))
    newtup=list()
    for i in mytuple:
        i=i.replace('tha', 'ta')
        i = i[:-3] if i.endswith('bai') else i
        newtup.append(''.join(i for i, _ in itertools.groupby(i)))
        newtup.sort()
    try:
            return ''.join(jellyfish.soundex(i) for i in newtup)
    except:
        return NULL
```

This python function works as expected and it returns the soundex value of each word from the given string. For e.g.

```
dropdup('Shantanu Shantanu Prabhakar Oak')
'o200p612s535'

dropdup('Oak Santanu Prabhakar')
'o200p612s535'
```

MySQL has built-in soundex function, but can I replicate the string manipulation python methods like removing and de-duplicating a few characters?

```
mysql> select concat( soundex('oak'), soundex('prabhakar'), soundex('shantanu')) as dropdup;
+---------------+
| dropdup       |
+---------------+
| O200P6126S535 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Are there any advantages / dis-advantages of using stored procedure for string manipulation ? what is the best practice?

Comment: In my opinion you would be better sticking with python. Sql (not just mysql) string manipulation is poor but then that's not what sql is designed for.

Comment: @shantanuo yes you can.